# Using abstract classes for applicationServices

Tags: entity-framework-core, abstract-class, dto, abp, applicationservice

I'm building an application on top of abp framework and struggle with a design decision I made.

I have an abstract class `step`, which can be one of the following:

```
 - Introduction
 - Regular 
 - Navigation 
 - Finish
```

These StepTypes are very similar to each other, so I chose to use an abstract class and a discriminator in efCore to save all entities into one table.

Now I want to use a single applicationService to work with these entities but I run into issues since abp doesn't know which explicit entityType to return after creation.

```
public class StepAppService :
    CrudAppService<
        BaseStep,                        //Abstract step entity
        BaseStepDto,                     //Abstract step for transfer
        Guid,                            //Primary key of the step entity
        PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto,  //Used for paging/sorting
        CreateUpdateBaseStepDto>,        //Absract step used to create/update a step
    IBaseStepAppService {

    // ..... other ....
    
    public async Task<BaseStepDto> CreateByTypeAsync(CreateUpdateBaseStepDto input)
    {
        // Try to pass an explicit type to the repository
        if(input.StepType == StepType.Introduction)
        {
            return await base.CreateAsync(ObjectMapper.Map<CreateUpdateBaseStepDto, CreateUpdateIntroductionStepDto>(input));
        }
        else if (input.StepType == StepType.Navigation)
        {
            return await base.CreateAsync(ObjectMapper.Map<CreateUpdateBaseStepDto, CreateUpdateNavigationStepDto>(input));
        }
        else if (input.StepType == StepType.Regular)
        {
            return await base.CreateAsync(ObjectMapper.Map<CreateUpdateBaseStepDto, CreateUpdateRegularStepDto>(input));
        }
        else if (input.StepType == StepType.Finish)
        {
            return await base.CreateAsync(ObjectMapper.Map<CreateUpdateBaseStepDto, CreateUpdateFinishStepDto>(input));
        }
        else
        {
            return await base.CreateAsync(ObjectMapper.Map<CreateUpdateBaseStepDto, CreateUpdateNavigationStepDto>(input));
        }
    }}
```

I feel like I'm following an off-beat path and there should be a better design-decision for my problem. Do you have any suggestions on how I can use different steps but keep the comfort of using one applicationService?

Thanks :)

Comment: You could (should) consider to stop using ABP. Apart from that, avoid inheritance whenever possible. Is it really necessary? What's the added value?

Comment: Thanks Gert :)
I was sure that "stop using abp" will be one of the first suggestions. :D
For now I'm stuck with it and it actually jump started the project super well.

Comment: But what about inheritance? In my experience it's hardly ever the best solution, esp. in the context of database design and ORMs.

Comment: You may use an abstract generic StepAppService class instead. Then you can create inheritors with Type parameters